# D3.js Stringify data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, stringify

I've just found a function called "stringify" and it looks like an amazing way to convert flat data to a Json style.

If this is true, it'll save me hours of recursive programming in ASP/SQL.

I have my code here : [Original code](https://jsfiddle.net/KenHart/hy6m4uan/16/)

And I'm trying to create a the same effect with data, which I have kind of worked out here, you can run this and it gives the same structure.

```
<script>

var data = [
 { "name" : "A", "parent":"null" },
 { "name" : "J", "parent":"A"},
 { "name" : "I", "parent":"A" },
 { "name" : "G", "parent":"A" },
 { "name" : "H", "parent":"A" },
 { "name" : "Cr", "parent":"B" },
 { "name" : "D", "parent":"Cr" },
 { "name" : "E", "parent":"Cr" },
 { "name" : "H", "parent":"A" },
 { "name" : "F", "parent":"Cr"},
 { "name" : "B", "parent":"A" }
];

// create a name: node map
var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
map[node.name] = node;
return map;

}, {});

// create the tree 
var tree = [];
data.forEach(function(node) {
// add to parent
var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
if (parent) {
    // create child 
    (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
        // add node 
        .push(node);
} else {
    // null or missing
    tree.push(node);
}
});


d3.select('body').append('pre').text(JSON.stringify(tree, null, '  '));
```

I'm now having a problem intergrating the two together ?!

It's probably something really easy - but staring and re-writing this after much coffee is doing me in.

Anyone got any hints ? It would be greatly appreciated and thank you for reading this - I don't mind if any of you GURU's modify or recreate the code I have already.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !

After a few expresso's I've sorted the functionality.

Its a Frankenstien job, however it works - which until I have learnt more I am happy with.

Using the line

```
  JSON.stringify(tree, null, '  ')
```

I've directly replaced the var n = ... string.